# Calculating Contribution Ratios for Elements with Changing Values

Tags: math

How can I calculate the contribution ratio for each element when there are multiple elements (A, B, C, etc.), and each element has values (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), and so on?
The formula for the result is: result = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + ...) / (y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + ...). The number of elements and their values can change dynamically.

Suppose there are only two elements, element A initially has values (x1, y1), and element B has values (x2, y2). Now, if element A changes to (x11, y11), and element B doesn't change, how do I calculate the contribution ratio for the final result for each element? In this specific case, I expect element A to have a 100% contribution ratio, and element B to have 0%.

Another case is when element A changes to (2x1, 2y1), and element B changes to (2x2, 2y2), resulting in no change in the final result. In this scenario, the contribution ratio for both elements A and B should be zero.

Can someone provide a step-by-step guide on how to calculate these contribution ratios?